# Homework help: Reading specific random lines of a text file

Tags: python, random, text-files, line

I have a text file listing names and addresses that looks like this:

```
Owners Details

Muammmar Gaddafi,
1 Alison Drive

Idi Amin,
45 Kings Road

Vladimir Lenin,
3 Bow Street

Saddam Hussein,
45 Wall Street

Pol Pot,
78 Abbey Road
```

I want my program to be able to read and print a random line from the file, how do I do this?

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: This is a great title... "specific random lines" :)

Comment: [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to read the whole file in (assuming that it is not gigantic) and to apply [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice).

```
import random

with open('testfile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(random.choice(lines))  # prints a random line from testfile.txt
```